# How to select html dom for more than 1 time with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to select html dom for more than 1 time with jQuery?

```
$a = $('#product').children;
$b = $a('div');
```

I would like to select the inner-element for the next use but not getting them child by child.

Is there any function to work with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to select divisions inside the `$('#product').`
say if the division have a class in common

then you can use `$('#product').children().find('.class')`
or
`$('#product').children('.class')`
or if there are no common class for the div then you can use
`$('#product').children('div')`
or

```
$('#product div')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna select the inner `div`, use this way:

```
$('#product').children("div");
```